# How to determine the fee payer?

Tags: web3.js

I'm working with a `UiParsedMessage` as documented here: https://docs.rs/solana-transaction-status/latest/solana_transaction_status/struct.UiParsedMessage.html

How can I determine the fee payer of a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element in the `account_keys` is the fee payer.  From the documentation:

> signatures: <array[string]> - A list of base-58 encoded signatures applied to the transaction. The list is always of length message.header.numRequiredSignatures and not empty. The signature at index i corresponds to the public key at index i in message.accountKeys. The first one is used as the transaction id.

And

> accountKeys: <array[string]> - List of base-58 encoded public keys used by the transaction, including by the instructions and for signatures. The first message.header.numRequiredSignatures public keys must sign the transaction.

You can read more about the structure at https://docs.solana.com/api/http#transaction-structure